# Jquery Time-Picker is hiding inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have included j-query time Picker in my html page.
But it is not showing properly.
I have attached the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK1bP.png).
click on the screenshot text. you can find the screenshot.
Please give me a solution for this.

Comment: no screenshots here..

Comment: No screenshots or code. Please include some code and tell us what you tried. Thanks.

Comment: Im not able to upload screenshot right now. my reputation is less

Comment: try to set CSS
$('.ui-datepicker ').css()

Comment: sir you can find screenshot now.

Comment: what are properties i have to add?

Comment: add some of your code and some css for the div containing the form

Answer (score 1):

Remove `overflow:hidden` from one of the parent divs (*i.e.,* the div that has vertical scroll). 
That should make it visible outside of container div itself.

Comment: on click of textfield   cant we make it appear top of textfied?

Comment: would need to see html before i could give more info.